# How do I get the last elements of an array in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, multidimensional-array

How do I pull the values from an array like you do with .map?  Here's my code:

```
counter = 0
ary = Array.new

puts "How many teams do you have to enter?"
hm = gets.to_i

until counter == hm do
  puts "Team City"
  city = gets.chomp

  puts "Team Name"
  team = gets.chomp

  ary.push([city, team])
  counter += 1
end

ary.map { |x, y|
  puts "City: #{x} | Team: #{y}"
}

print "The last team entered was: "
ary.last
```

The end result looks like this:

```
City: Boston | Team: Bruins
City: Toronto | Team: Maple Leafs
The last team entered was: 
=> ["Toronto", "Maple Leafs"]
```

But I want the last line to read

```
The last team entered was: Toronto Maple Leafs
```

How do I get my values in that line without the =>, brackets and quotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use print instead of puts when you don't want a new line character at the end of the line for example when getting user input, furthermore you can also use `#{variable}` to print within the same line using puts:

```
counter = 0
ary = Array.new

print "How many teams do you have to enter? "
hm = gets.to_i

until counter == hm do
  print "Team #{counter + 1} City: "
  city = gets.chomp

  print "Team #{counter + 1} Name: "
  team = gets.chomp

  ary.push([city, team])
  counter += 1
end

ary.map { |x, y| puts "City: #{x} | Team: #{y}" }

puts "The last team entered was: #{ary.last.join(' ')}"
```

**Example Usage:**

```
How many teams do you have to enter?  2
Team 1 City:  Boston
Team 1 Name:  Bruins
Team 2 City:  Toronto
Team 2 Name:  Maple Leafs
City: Boston | Team: Bruins
City: Toronto | Team: Maple Leafs
The last team entered was: Toronto Maple Leafs
```

Try it [here!](https://repl.it/Fo1i/2)

Comment: At first I was all "Nawwww I like my format" then I tried out yours and oh yeah it's wayyyy better.  Shit's lit, fam!  I'm just learning Ruby and this was great.  Thanks!

Comment: `ary.map { |x, y| puts "City: #{x} | Team: #{y}" }` is abusing `map`, `each` iterator **must be used there**.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you question is “how to join string array elements into a single string,” and [`Array#join`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-join) comes to the rescue:

```
["Toronto", "Maple Leafs"].join(' ')
#⇒ "Toronto Maple Leafs"
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way with `*`:

```
puts ["Toronto", "Maple Leafs"] * ', '
#Toronto, Maple Leafs
#=> nil
```

But I don't think anyone uses this notation, so as recommended in another answer use `join`.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
team_last = ary.last
puts "The last team entered was:" + team_last[0] + team_last[1]
```

Comment: Have you ever read a question, or you answer directly to titles?

Comment: Owh, i am sorry. I hope this can help

Answer (score 0):

As per your code `ary.last` itself return an array so first you would need to convert it to a string by joining the two elements in the array by  `ary.last.join(' ')` and then you will have to interpolate it with the your message string i.e `"The last team entered was: #{ary.last.join(' ')}"`

The last two lines of your code would change to :

```
print "The last team entered was: #{ary.last.join(' ')}"
```